# GridView фильтрация и сортировка количества связанных моделей

Tags: yii2, gridview

У меня есть таблица author и у неё есть связь один ко многим. Я хотел бы сделать сортировку и поиск по количеству связанных моделей books, но пока понял только, как их получить и отобразить, если может кто помочь, помогите пожалуйста.

```js
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "authors".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $patronymic
 * @property string $surname
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 *
 * @property Books[] $books
 */
class Author extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'authors';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'required'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['name', 'patronymic', 'surname'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'patronymic' => 'Patronymic',
            'surname' => 'Surname',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        ];
    }

    public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Books::className(), ['author_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getAmountBooks()
    {

        return $this->getBooks()->count();
    }

    /*public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }*/
}
```

```css
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\models\Author;

/**
 * SearchAuthor represents the model behind the search form of `frontend\models\author`.
 */
class SearchAuthor extends Author
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'patronymic', 'surname', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Author::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'patronymic', $this->patronymic])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'surname', $this->surname]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}

<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\models\SearchAuthor */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Authors';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="author-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create author', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Create book', ['books/create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Library', ['books/index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'name',
            'patronymic',
            'surname',
            'created_at',
            //'updated_at',

            [
                'attribute'=>'id',
                'label'=>'Amount Books',
                'content'=>function($data) {
                    return $data->getAmountBooks();
                },
            ],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

```html
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\models\Author;

/**
 * SearchAuthor represents the model behind the search form of `frontend\models\author`.
 */
class SearchAuthor extends Author
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'patronymic', 'surname', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Author::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'patronymic', $this->patronymic])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'surname', $this->surname]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант #1:**

1. В модели `Author` добавить "виртуальный" атрибут `$amount_books`:

   ```
   class Author extends ActiveRecord
   {
       public $amount_books;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Сделать дополнения в `SearchAuthor` - смотрите мои комментарии в коде.

   ```
   class SearchAuthor extends Author 
   {
       // добавить 'amount_books' в rules()
       public function rules()
       {
           return [
               [['id'], 'integer'],
               [['name', 'patronymic', 'surname', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'amount_books'], 'safe'],
           ];
       }

       ...

       public function search($params)
       {
           /*
           Изменить ключевой запрос на выборку, обернув его ещё в один `SELECT`
            (`SELECT * FROM (<текущий $query>)`). Только так `amount_books` можно 
           получить "снаружи", чтобы потом по нему была фильтрация `WHERE`, ведь 
           `WHERE` по `COUNT` сделать нельзя в одном запросе. 
           $subQuery - это по сути старый $query + join с количеством books.
           */
           $subQuery = Author::find()
               ->select(['{{%author}}.*', 'amount_books' => new \yii\db\Expression('COUNT({{%books}}.id)')])
               ->joinWith(['books'])
               ->groupBy('{{%author}}.id');

           $query = Author::find()->from($subQuery);

           $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
               'query' => $query,
           ]);

           // добавить 'amount_books' в сортировку
           $dataProvider->sort->attributes['amount_books'] = [
               'asc' => ['amount_books' => SORT_ASC],
               'desc' => ['amount_books' => SORT_DESC],
           ];

           $this->load($params);

           if (!$this->validate()) {
               // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
               // $query->where('0=1');
               return $dataProvider;
           }

           // grid filtering conditions
           $query->andFilterWhere([
               'id' => $this->id,
               'created_at' => $this->created_at,
               'updated_at' => $this->updated_at
           ]);

           // добавить 'amount_books' в фильтрацию
           $query->andFilterWhere(['amount_books' => $this->amount_books]);

           $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
               ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'patronymic', $this->patronymic])
               ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'surname', $this->surname]);

           return $dataProvider;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Изменить колонки для `GridView`:

   ```
   <?= GridView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       'filterModel' => $searchModel,
       'columns' => [
           ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

           'id',
           'name',
           'patronymic',
           'surname',
           'created_at',
           //'updated_at',

           'amount_books', // Просто указать атрибут. Название колонки можно добавить в attributeLabels() в Author

           ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
       ],
   ]); ?>
   ```
4. В модели `Books` так же должна быть указана связь с моделью `Author`:

   ```
   public function getAuthor()
   {
       return $this->hasOne(Author::className(), ['id' => 'author_id']);
   }
   ```

В этой реализации можно убрать метод `getAmountBooks()`, если он больше нигде не нужен.

**Вариант #2:**

Добавить физическое поле `amount_books` в таблице `author` и обновлять его при обновлении `books` (добавлении, удалении, смене `author_id`), хранить в нём текущее количество книг автора. Тогда обёртка для запроса не нужна, `DataProvider` и `GridView` настраиваются как для обычного скалярного атрибута.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое расцеловал бы если смог, а то 2 дня гуглил так и не нагуглил как это сделать)

Comment: @Vladimir Рада, что помогло) Отметьте мой ответ галочкой как решение вашего вопроса, это поможет другим увидеть, что решение рабочее.